# .class expected error when calling boolean method

Tags: java

I am getting an error when trying to call a boolean method from another class. I have tried editing the way I am calling the method, but none have worked so far. I'm posting the code I had for both classes for the clearest error message i got which was the ".class" expected error.

```
public class Date
{
public int Day;
public int Month;
public int Year;
public Date(int myDay, int myMonth, int myYear){
    Month = myMonth;
    Day = myDay;
    Year = myYear;
    }
public int daysIs(){

    return Day;
}
public int monthIs(){

    return Month;
}
public int yearIs(){

    return Year;
}
public boolean isLeapYear(int Year){
    if (Year % 4 != 0){
        return false;
    }else if (Year % 400 == 0) {
        return true;
    }else if (Year % 100 == 0){
        return false;
    }else {
        return true;
        }
}
Date mydate = new Date(Day, Month, Year);
}
```

For the first class here it compiles with no errors. The method I am trying to call is the isLeapYear method near the end. My second class always has some kind of error when I try to call the method.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class DateJDialog
{
 public static void main(String[]args)
{
     String input;
     int Day;
     int Month;
     int Year;
     //prompt the day
     input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the 2 digit day of the month: ");
     Day = Integer.parseInt(input);
     //prompt the month
     input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the 2 digit month of the year: ");
     Month = Integer.parseInt(input);
     //prompt the year
     input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the 4 digit year: ");
     Year = Integer.parseInt(input);
     Date inputDate = new Date(Day,Month,Year);
     if( inputDate.isLeapYear(int Year)= false){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The given year was NOT a Leap Year.");
        }else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The given year WAS a Leap Year.");
    }


}
}
```

The errors always happen on the first line of the if statement near the end.

Comment: What do you think `=` is? What do you think it does? Why?

Comment: Don't put the type in when you call a method, just when you declare it.

Comment: I tried removing the 'int' in front of Year but It gives me the Unexpected type error, and says that Year is a Value instead of a Variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write this line of if condition.

```
  if (inputDate.isLeapYear(int Year)= false) {...}
```

Like this:

```
  if (!inputDate.isLeapYear(2015)) {
```

You don't specify a data type of a parameter when you call a method. Also, `=` is an assigning operator, in conditions we use a comparing operator `==`.

There is no need of comparing a boolean value to another boolean value, so `==` is pointless in this case.

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much! I'll remember it in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Your thinking too hard, you should take it simple when programming. You don't need the type when calling a method, only do this when you declare it.

Comment: Actually, it is not permitted when calling it, unless of course you are casting the type.